# Price GoogleMaps SDK mobile aplication (2022)

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, google-maps

I am currently working on a native Android application with kotlin and IOS with swift in which I am integrating the google maps sdk.

I am integrating a simple map where a marker will be drawn with a specific coordinate (latitude and longitude).

My question is if the google maps sdk has any cost with the mentioned features, I have reviewed the documentation but I am a bit confused.

- For example in the following [link](https://mapsplatform.google.com/intl/es/pricing/) (7 dollars)
  [image]
- And also in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing) mentions something else (0 dollars)
  [image]

I hope you can help me since I'm a little confused or maybe I'm not understanding the billing method?

Thanks, excuse my english :D

Comment: I you scroll down you see that you will get charged for the number of request you are doing to open a map. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#dynamic-maps

Comment: As I read it, if you load a map without specifying a map id, it is free and unlimited. If you specify a map id then it costs you $7 per 1000 loads, but you get $200 free (about 28000 loads) per month